# Зачем в Python использовать 'from decouple import config' для получения логина-пароля вместо обычного импорта переменных из локального файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Для того, чтобы уберечь данные для авторизации от выкладки в репозиторий в сети нашел такой способ: https://nuancesprog.ru/p/12370/

Помимо того, что мне не удалось заставить его работать (второй вопрос этого топика), прошу объяснить чем он лучше простого импорта переменных из локально сохраненного файла типа:

```
from auth import login, password
```

**auth.py:**

```
login = 'xxx'
password = 'yyy'
```

2. И, если этот способ все-таки лучше, чем импорт переменных из локального файла, то прошу пояснить, как исправить ошибку

   ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'decouple' (/home/UserName/PycharmProjects/ProjectName/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/decouple/_*init_*.py)

`pip install python-decouple` был выполнен успешно. "Обычный" `decouple` и не устанавливался.

Кроме того, PyCharm указывает на ошибку и до попытки исполнения кода:
[image: PyCharm: cannot find referece 'config' in 'init.py']

Comment: 1: Затем, что py-файл - это код. Если его не добавлять в git, то у другого человека, который будет пытаться с этим репозиторием работать, код работать не будет, и не будет понятно, каких переменных не хватает. А если логин и пароль в git добавить, то вы делитесь ими потенциально с неопределенным кругом лиц (особенно если у вас публичный репозиторий). Через decouple можно указать значения по умолчанию, и даже если не указывать, то будет видно, каких значений не хватает.

Comment: 2: пробуйте `pip unistall decouple` потом `pip install python-decouple`. "Обычный" decouple - это вообще про другое.

Comment: @insolor пробовал. получаю ответ `WARNING: Skipping decouple as it is not installed`.

Comment: Код-то запускается? Если запускается, а ошибка только в PyCharm, то пробуйте в PyCharm очистить кэш через File - Invalidate caches

Comment: Если не запускается, пробуйте принудительно переустановить python-decouple через `pip install -U python-decouple` (предполагаю, что pip вы в виртуальном окружении проекта запускаете)

Comment: @insolor код не запускается. ошибка та же. чистка кэша ситуацию не изменила. при попытке переустановить python-decouple как вы предложили, получаю ответ:   
`pip install -U python-decouple
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: python-decouple in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.6)`

Comment: Значит вы pip не в виртуальном окружении запускаете, а глобально. Запускайте его в проекте через терминал PyCharm, или вручную активируйте виртуальное окружение в cmd.

Comment: * не в cmd, а в терминале, вижу что у вас linux-подобное окружение

Comment: @insolor да, в этом дело. заработало. спасибо! если не сложно, поясните как реализовать второй вариант - активировать виртуальное окружение в терминале. и, если оформите свой комментарий ответом, отмечу его как решение